# I want to iterate all subdirectories using os.walk, but only print links without stepping in. How can I lower complexity?

Tags: python, algorithm, file-io

I have a piece of code I have been working on that currently looks like this:

```
  def buildManifestFile(self):
    manifestFile = self.createManifestFileForWriting(self.manifest_target)
    symlinks = []
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(self.basedir, followlinks=True):
      if self.isIncluded(self.includes,self.excludes,subdir[len(self.basedir):]) and not any(link in subdir for link in symlinks):
        if not os.path.islink(subdir):                                      ## symlinks should be listed as files, not followed.
          manifestFile.write('%dir "' + subdir +  '"\n')
        else:
          manifestFile.write('"' + subdir + '"\n')
          symlinks.append(subdir)
          continue
        for fileName in files:
          fileNameWithSubdir = '"' + subdir + "/" + fileName + '"\n'
          if self.isIncluded(self.includes,self.excludes,fileNameWithSubdir):
            manifestFile.write(fileNameWithSubdir)
    self.closeManifestFile(manifestFile)
```

I want to essentially traverse a directory, hitting all subdirectories, files, and symlinks, but I do not want to follow symlinks, as it creates a lot of redundancy in my output. I actually just want to print them as a file. The above code seems to work fine, but the part that bothers me is that it grows pretty fast in complexity as I use it on a directory with many symlinks.

Comment: The problem with links is that it can potentially add cycles to your directory tree that are difficult to detect.

Comment: If you don't want to follow symlinks, why are you explicitly asking Python to follow symlinks with `followlinks=True`?

Comment: When I set it up to NOT follow them, e.g followlinks=False, it did not emit them to the output at all, because it lists them as Dirs IIRC and I do not want a 3rd level of iteration here.

Answer (score 1):

The os.walk does per default list the Symlinks, but does not follow them. See what is left when you loop the folders in os.walk tail.

```
def oswalker(path):
    walked = list(os.walk(path))
    toplevel = walked[0]
    poss_folder = toplevel[1]
    folders = walked[1:]

    for folder in folders:
        # symlinks will be listed in the walk folders, but are not
        # present in the tail of the walk list
        check = [i for i,x in enumerate(poss_folder) if x in folder[0]]
        if check:
            poss_folder.pop(check[0])

    print "Symlinks %s", poss_folder


oswalker('.')
```

Comment: @catagon87 does it lower the complexity for you?